# unlink vs remove in c++

Tags: c++, unix, posix, erase

What is the difference between remove and unlink functions in C++?

Comment: I doubt you will notice any difference in speed. Making the choice will not be the costly part of the operation.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Apart from the fact that unlink is unix-specific (as pointed out by Chris), we read in the POSIX manual:

> If path does not name a directory, remove(path) is equivalent to unlink(path).
>   If path names a directory, remove(path) is equivalent to rmdir(path).

As for the directory-passed `unlink`, we read:

> The path argument must not name a directory unless the process has appropriate privileges and the implementation supports using unlink() on directories. (...) Applications should use rmdir() to remove a directory.

Answer (score 23):

`remove` is portable, and `unlink` is Unix-specific. :-P

Answer (score 8):

The `remove()` function removes the file or directory specified by path.

If path specifies a directory, `remove(path)` is the equivalent of
`rmdir(path)`.  Otherwise, it is the equivalent of `unlink(path)`.

From: `man remove`.

Good Luck ;)

Comment: Note that that's specific to Unix-like systems (which is perfectly appropriate given the tags on the question). The ISO C standard defines the `remove` function; it says nothing about directories. POSIX extends its behavior as you describe.

Answer (score 5):

unlink is not unix-specific, i don't know why people're saying that. see io.h. although you'll probably have to do something like

```
#define unlink _unlink
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c3tczd6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2da4hk1d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: unlink is a Posix function.  MS included many Posix functions in the C runtime headers for their compiler, but this polluted the namespace.  To be more compliant with the C standard, MS later replaced some of the Posix functions they had provided with versions prefixed with an underscore (and removed others).  Leading underscores are reserved to the implementation.  In general, C runtime functions are more portable than Posix functions.  Posix functions, in general, are pretty unix-centric, even though some non-unix OSes may provide some Posix support.

Comment: No, we do not agree.  unlink is a Posix function.  Posix was an attempt to standardize Unix-derived operating systems.  _unlink is a different function that works on a non-Unix operating system.

Comment: It may be a unix function, but you can define it so that if it finds unlink in the code when it's the windows OS, it actually goes to the definition of _unlink. I think that's what @bviktor was alluding to.

Answer (score -1):

`remove()` is part of the C++ standard (N4860 29.11.14.30). `unlink()` is not.