# Simple Delete File Program in ANSI C for Windows

Tags: windows, file-handling, ansi-c

Looking for a simple program to a delete a file written in ANSI C.
Just as an example how would you delete a file at "C:\test.txt" with C?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/unlink

Comment: possible duplicate of [unlink vs remove in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192415/unlink-vs-remove-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete a file from the OS using the `remove()` function. Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    if(remove("HELLO.txt") == -1)
        perror("Error in deleting a file");
    return 0;
}
```

The `remove()` function is defined in `stdio.h`. [Here are some docs.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `remove` function. I believe it is in "stdio.h"

Answer (score 1):

remove or unlink

remove is declared in 'stdio.h'

unlink is declared in 'unistd.h'

unlink is posix function, remove is ansi C function. They all work fine in windows.

unlink only delete files, remove can be used to delete directories.